# Stripe payout error Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Sorry, you don't have any external accounts in that currency (usd)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Below is my Stripe payout code. When I run this code I am getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: Sorry, you don't have any external accounts in that currency (usd). in E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php:210 from API request 'req_r9TZvcfX1ac6Az' Stack trace: #0 E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(173): Stripe\ApiRequestor::_specificAPIError('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Object(Stripe\Util\CaseInsensitiveArray), Array, Array) #1 E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(473): Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleErrorResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Object(Stripe\Util\CaseInsensitiveArray), Array) #2 E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php(126): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n "error": {\n...', 400, Object(Stripe\Util\CaseInsensitiveArray)) #3 E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiOperations\Request.php(57): Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/payou in E:\xammp-php-7.0\htdocs\grumbledog_web\app\vendors\stripe-php\lib\ApiRequestor.php on line 210

My code:

```
public function payout() {
    require_once('vendors/stripe-php/init.php');
    $stripe = array(
        "secret_key" => cr("DealConfig.secret_key"),
        "publishable_key" => cr("DealConfig.publishable_key")
    );
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                "description" => "Customer for payout"
    ));
    $customer_id = $customer->id;
    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($customer_id);
    $bank_data = \Stripe\Token::create(array(
                "bank_account" => array(
                    "country" => "US",
                    "currency" => "usd",
                    "account_holder_name" => "Charlotte Thomas",
                    "account_holder_type" => "individual",
                    "routing_number" => "110000000",
                    "account_number" => "000123456789"
                )
    ));
    $bank_token = $bank_data->id;
    $bank_account = \Stripe\Customer::createSource(
                    $customer_id, ['source' => $bank_token]
    );
    $payout_data = \Stripe\Payout::create(array(
                "amount" => 1000,
                "currency" => "usd",
    ));
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($payout_data);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, that code is really not how you do a Payout in Stripe at all, so I'd suggest starting over from the [Connect docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect). You need to use Connect, and create [Account objects](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/accounts), and add [ExternalAccounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts#bank-accounts) to them. Customer objects like you're using here can *not* be paid out to, they are only for paying money *to* _you_. You have to use Connect and create other Stripe Accounts and you pay out to those if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: how can i payout to seller bank account number using curl? let me know line by line just api call url. It is big help for me